# Python script converted to class or imported as module is executed much slower?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

**EDIT 2**
After some more testing I've noticed the problem explained below even importing the script as a module. (changed title accordingly)

---

I'm working on an IoT project that requires a rotary encoder connected to a Raspberry pi.

I've found some python libraries and various script (usually based on timing) to work with the encoder, but none of these is working reliably.
Major problem, usually, is when you spin the encoder quickly: the values you get goes up and down not following the spin direction.
Maybe the problem is originated by the raspberry hardware not fast enough.

However, I wrote a script (based on gpiozero library) which is definitely not perfect, it miss some input from the encoder from time to time, but it resolve the above problem: values goes up when you spin clockwise and goes down the other way.  And that's all I need.

Then I've tried to make a class of that code (in case I've to use multiple encoder) but doing so my code is missing many input from the device, and it's barely usable.
I'm still learning python and all this stuff so I don't know if problem it's in my code or if it could be the limited hardware of the raspberry.

**EDITED WITH MORE INFORMATION**

---

With every input from the encoder (spinning the encoder of just one step/click) you get 4 different event as you can realize from the sequence:

SPINNING CLOCKWISE

```
dt pressed (dt value = 1)
clk pressed (clk value = 1)
dt released (dt value = 0)
clk released (clk value = 0)
```

SPINNING COUNTERCLOCKWISE

```
clk pressed (clk value = 1)    
dt pressed (dt value = 1)
clk released (clk value = 0)
dt released (dt value = 0)
```

So in my code I simply check this sequence to determine the direction and to avoid undesired values, because spinning the encoder quickly gives unexpected values.
It works for the script but using the class very very often the sequence is not even completed. For example you get only `dt pressed -> dt released` when spinning clockwise or only `clk pressed -> clk released` when spinning ccw. This behavior makes me think the code is not executed fast enough.

---

This is the script code:

```
from gpiozero import Button


'''
Sequence of values that the rotary encoder output for every step/click.
Sequence -> dt 1 / clk 1 / dt 0 / clk 0
Sequence <- clk 1 / dt 1 / clk 0 / dt 0
'''


def clk_pressed():
    global sequence
    if len(sequence) > 2:
        sequence.clear()
    sequence.append('clk1')


def clk_released():
    global sequence, counter
    sequence.append('clk0')
    if sequence == sequence_up:
        if counter < max:
            counter += scale
        print(counter)
        sequence.clear()


def dt_pressed():
    global sequence
    if len(sequence) > 2:
        sequence.clear()
    sequence.append('dt1')


def dt_released():
    global sequence, counter
    sequence.append('dt0')
    if sequence == sequence_down:
        if counter > min:
            counter -= scale
        print(counter)
        sequence.clear()


clk = Button(27)
clk.when_pressed = clk_pressed
clk.when_released = clk_released


dt = Button(22)
dt.when_pressed = dt_pressed
dt.when_released = dt_released

sequence = []
sequence_up = ['dt1', 'clk1', 'dt0', 'clk0']
sequence_down = ['clk1', 'dt1', 'clk0', 'dt0']
counter = 0
min = 0
max = 100
scale = 5


message = input("Press ENTER to quit")
```

And this is the Class:

```
from gpiozero import Button


'''
Sequence of values that the rotary encoder output for every step/click.
Sequence -> dt 1 / clk 1 / dt 0 / clk 0
Sequence <- clk 1 / dt 1 / clk 0 / dt 0
'''


class Rotary:

    sequence = []
    sequence_up = ['dt1', 'clk1', 'dt0', 'clk0']
    sequence_down = ['clk1', 'dt1', 'clk0', 'dt0']
    counter = 0
    last_counter = 0
    clk_input = None
    dt_input = None

    def __init__(self, clk, dt, min, max, delta):
        self.clk = clk
        self.dt = dt
        self.min = min
        self.max = max
        self.delta = delta

        def clk_pressed():
            if len(self.sequence) > 2:
                self.sequence.clear()
            self.sequence.append('clk1')

        def clk_released():
            self.sequence.append('clk0')
            if self.sequence == self.sequence_up:
                if self.counter < self.max:
                    self.counter = self.counter + self.delta
                return self.counter
                self.sequence.clear()

        def dt_pressed():
            if len(self.sequence) > 2:
                self.sequence.clear()
            self.sequence.append('dt1')

        def dt_released():
            self.sequence.append('dt0')
            if self.sequence == self.sequence_down:
                if self.counter > self.min:
                    self.counter = self.counter - self.delta
                return self.counter
                self.sequence.clear()

        self.clk_input = Button(self.clk)
        self.clk_input.when_pressed = clk_pressed
        self.clk_input.when_released = clk_released

        self.dt_input = Button(self.dt)
        self.dt_input.when_pressed = dt_pressed
        self.dt_input.when_released = dt_released

    def watch(self):
        while True:
             if self.counter != self.last_counter:
                print(self.counter)
                self.last_counter = self.counter
```

So now I can create the instance and call the watch method even using threading:

```
from rotary import Rotary
import threading


my_rotary = Rotary(clk=27, dt=22, min=0, max=100, delta=5)

my_thread = threading.Thread(target=my_rotary.watch)
my_thread.start()

# while True:
#     my_rotary.watch()
```

Sorry for the long post.
Any hint is really appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you expect it to speed up? Classes are much more complicated than functions for language to handle.

Comment: Not to speed up, but I didn't expect it to slow down this much either.
But if the problem is the Class then I can just stick to script.

Comment: Did you use threading for the first script, too? Python isn't good at multithreading.

Comment: No but using the class I get same result even with a while loop without using threading.

Comment: Did you use `while` also for first script (it doesn't seem so)? If not, maybe add a `time.sleep(0.1)` or so to while loop or try without the loop.

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the while loop. I've updated the post with more information.